# Exponential regression function Python

Tags: python, numpy, regression, sympy, exponential

I am trying to implement a exponential regression function. sp stands for sympy. I use numpy and sympy. Firstly, in func_exp I tried to use np.exp but it generated an error (attribute error), so I decided to use sympy instead. Well, this is the code

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import matrix_rank
import scipy 
import scipy.integrate

import random 

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

from sympy import integrate
import sympy as sp

x, y = sp.symbols('x, y')

sp.init_printing(use_unicode=True,use_latex='mathjax')
def exponential_regression (x_data, y_data):
   def func_exp(x, a, b):
       return a*sp.exp(b*x)
   popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(func_exp, x_data, y_data)
   a = popt[0] # componente a, Parámetro ÓPTimo (popt).
   b = popt[1] # componente b, Parámetro ÓPTimo (popt).
   plt.figure()
   puntos = plt.plot(x_data, y_data, 'x', color='xkcd:maroon')
   curva_regresion = plt.plot(x_data, func_exp(x_data, a, b),    color='xkcd:teal')
   plt.show(puntos, curva_regresion)
   return func_exp(x, a, b)
```

I try to execute:

```
  x_data = np.arange(0, 51) # Crea un array de 0 a 50.
  y_data = np.array([0.001, 0.199, 0.394, 0.556, 0.797, 0.891, 1.171, 1.128, 1.437, 
          1.525, 1.720, 1.703, 1.895, 2.003, 2.108, 2.408, 2.424,2.537, 
          2.647, 2.740, 2.957, 2.58, 3.156, 3.051, 3.043, 3.353, 3.400, 
          3.606, 3.659, 3.671, 3.750, 3.827, 3.902, 3.976, 4.048, 4.018, 
          4.286, 4.353, 4.418, 4.382, 4.444, 4.485, 4.465, 4.600, 4.681, 
          4.737, 4.792, 4.845, 4.909, 4.919, 5.100])
  exponential_regression(x_data, y_data)
```

And I get:

```
exponential_regression(x_data, y_data)
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-122-ee7c243ae4b0>", line 1, in <module>
exponential_regression(x_data, y_data)

 File "/Volumes/TOSHIBA/spline.py", line 35, in exponential_regression
popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(func_exp, x_data, y_data)

 File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 742, in curve_fit
res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)

 File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 387, in leastsq
gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)

 error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.
```

What is wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you bringing in sympy?

Comment: @user2357112 because when I used sympy I got np.array([np.exp(x)*x])
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-99-1572dbe878a4>", line 1, in <module>
    np.array([np.exp(x)*x])

AttributeError: 'Symbol' object has no attribute 'exp'

Comment: That problem wouldn't have occurred if you hadn't brought in sympy.

Comment: @user2357112 anyway, i use sympy later in my program...

Comment: I don't think the equation you are using has the same shape as your data - make a scatterplot of the data only and you can see this. The Stirling equation is a much better fit to your data, try the equation "y = a * (exp(bx) - 1.0) / b" with fitted parameters a =  1.8641552758230268E-01 and b = -2.8402723064116495E-02

Comment: @JamesPhillips well that's what the assignment tells us to do... use a*exp(b*x). I cannot change it...

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't ask for `a * np.exp(b * x) + c`? For this you get a good fit, but how can you get a good fit for your function? It will never go through (0, 0).

Comment: @Mr.T defintely yes, it says that the exponential regression must follow y = a*exp(b*x)...

Comment: Tip: Test your fit function with a real exponential data set, not the one you have.

Comment: @Mr. T how can I test it if doesn’t work? 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a minimal example for your fit function as close as possible to your code but removing all unnecessary elements. You can easily remove `c` to adhere to your requirements:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def func_exp(x, a, b, c):
        #c = 0
        return a * np.exp(b * x) + c

def exponential_regression (x_data, y_data):
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(func_exp, x_data, y_data, p0 = (-1, 0.01, 1))
    print(popt)
    puntos = plt.plot(x_data, y_data, 'x', color='xkcd:maroon', label = "data")
    curva_regresion = plt.plot(x_data, func_exp(x_data, *popt), color='xkcd:teal', label = "fit: {:.3f}, {:.3f}, {:.3f}".format(*popt))
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
    return func_exp(x_data, *popt)

x_data = np.arange(0, 51) 
y_data = np.array([0.001, 0.199, 0.394, 0.556, 0.797, 0.891, 1.171, 1.128, 1.437, 
        1.525, 1.720, 1.703, 1.895, 2.003, 2.108, 2.408, 2.424,2.537, 
        2.647, 2.740, 2.957, 2.58, 3.156, 3.051, 3.043, 3.353, 3.400, 
        3.606, 3.659, 3.671, 3.750, 3.827, 3.902, 3.976, 4.048, 4.018, 
        4.286, 4.353, 4.418, 4.382, 4.444, 4.485, 4.465, 4.600, 4.681, 
        4.737, 4.792, 4.845, 4.909, 4.919, 5.100])
exponential_regression(x_data, y_data)
```

Output with `c = 0`:
[image]

Output with `c != 0`:
[image]

Main changes explained:

1. Removed `sympy` - it has nothing to do with the fitting procedure.
2. The definition of the exponential fit function is placed outside `exponential_regression`, so it can be accessed from other parts of the script. It uses `np.exp` because you work with numpy arrays in scipy.
3. Added the [parameter `p0`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) which contains the initial guesses for the parameters. Fit functions are often sensitive to this initial guess because of local extrema.
4. Unpack variables with `*popt` to make it more flexible for different numbers of variables. `a = popt[0]`, `b = popt[1]`, etc.
5. Removed unnecessary imports. [Keep your namespace free from clutter.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2386740/8881141)

Comment: Cool! Two questions: (1) How did you determine p0 = (-1, 0.01, 1)? (2) I thought that this data set has a hyperbolic best fit, but now, with the constant c... it turns out that the exponential is better?

Comment: (1) Guesstimates. From (0, 0) we can conclude that a + c = 0. The shape tells us that a < 0. And b should have been set according to the shape to an initial parameter of -0.1 - but hey, it converged nonetheless. (2) Whether it is a better fit than another function is unclear. You have to compare the deviation using pcov to get a measure, how good the fit for each function is. But it surely looks well fitted.

Comment: yes it looks so, so that's why I started doubting.. thanks